# Python 3.8.2 installed, OpenAIi installed but OpanAI is not getting recognised in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, terminal, openai-api

Installed Python 3, Also OpenAI through pip3 but when I am using the following command

`python3 show openai`

then it shows the error as following:

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'show': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can you let me know what I am doing wrong here? I have attached the screenshot from terminal.

[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVOzP.jpg)

I have tried to reset/hard reset the terminal,I tried to set the default path

Comment: What is `python3 show`? I don't recognize it as a command line argument. If you're just trying to confirm openai was installed correctly, maybe `python -c "import openai; print(openai.version.VERSION)"` is what you need?

Comment: Openai is installed but it is not getting recognised. It gives me the following error.

zsh: command not found: openai

Comment: I have a similar error: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`...